# pyplot from matplotlib shows error when trying to import it in code

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

I'm using IDLE for Python 2.7 on a mac and I'm just trying to use matplotlib.pyplot but I get an error when importing it in my code. Here's a simple example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

followed by its error:

> RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xa but this version
>   of numpy is 0x9
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   File "/Users/patricksaunders/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py",
>   line 29, in 
>       import matplotlib.colorbar   File "/Users/patricksaunders/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py",
>   line 32, in 
>       import matplotlib.artist as martist   File "/Users/patricksaunders/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py",
>   line 14, in 
>       from .transforms import (Bbox, IdentityTransform, TransformedBbox,   File
>   "/Users/patricksaunders/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py",
>   line 39, in 
>       from matplotlib._path import (affine_transform, count_bboxes_overlapping_bbox, ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray
>   failed to import

I installed matplotlib using
    conda install matplotlib
since I have Anaconda installed. Anybody know why I'm getting this error?

Comment: You could try updating numpy.

Comment: Does it work from the command line, i.e. not with  IDLE?